# AngularJS in HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to create a table with products on a certain menu of a store.
The table is divided by categories (product categories) and for every category the desired products should be shown under his category.

Something like:[image]

I am able to get the different categories in my html but when I want to use ng-repeat on table rows or table headers I get nothing...

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
<th colspan="5">Menu items</th>
</tr> 
<tr ng-app="categories" ng-cloak="" ng-controller="category" ng-repeat= "c in categories">
<th>{{c[1]}}</th>
</tr>
```

**AngularJS**

```
categories = angular.module('categories', []);
categories.controller("category",function($scope, $http){
    var serviceBase = 'api/';
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'categories').then(function (results) {
        $scope.categories = results.data;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++){
            var categories = $scope.categories[i];
        }
});
});
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
<table ng-app="categories" ng-cloak="" ng-controller="category">
<tr>
<th>Menu items</th>
</tr>  
<tr ng-repeat= "c in categories">
<th>{{c[1]}}</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code:

```
         categories = angular.module('categories', []);

         categories.controller("category",function($scope, $http){
             var serviceBase = 'api/';
             $http.get(serviceBase + 'categories').then(function (results) {
                 var categorie = results.data;
                 for(var i = 0; i < categorie.length; i++){
                     $scope.categories = categorie[i];
                 }
         });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have `ng-repeat` of on your `ng-app` & `ng-controller` div. Even you don't need to do for loop. You categories does have category in it. You can access those inside `ng-repeat` using `c` only no need to specifying any index in it.

**Markup**

```
<body class="table table-hover" ng-app="categories" ng-cloak="" ng-controller="category" >
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Menu items</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in categories">
        <th>{{c}}</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Your solution also works but now I need to show the matching products for each category under the shown categories by {{c}} as shown in the picture above?

Comment: you may need to create a filter your own custom filter